# Android screen has a half-transparent black layer after asking for permissions the first time

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

So, this peccadillo has lingered for too long in my application but there doesn't seems to be any advice related to the problem I face.

I made an Android application which works as an online folder browsing mechanism by showing content in form of folder/file icons and text using a Custom Gridview. The problem I face is only occurs for once and not the second time when I replicate the same process.

The process is of asking for a permission to access the external storage and after use denies or accept it, the screen turns a bit of a semi-transparent layer of black and goes away after I close the application. It only happens in the Activity where GridView is used as a part of the whole layout. Obviously it wouldn't pop up the second time when I accept the permission but when I deny the permission and replicate the same process, the issue doesn't happen again once it's occurred but I'd like to assess what could be behind this weirdness.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using Layout Inspector to check what windows and views are actually displayed when this happens?

Comment: @SpaceBison Yes I did. There doesn't seem to be any issues when looked from LI. Let me clarify, everything works as its supposed to, but with that layer of semi-transparent black as you can notice in the image. This would extend even outside the app to the whole phone but that's all, everything works when I click on it so I doubt if other views are displayed.